# What could cause an invalid function reference when calling virtual base functions?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have tried to debug a segfault in my application, but can not figure out what the problem is. It would be too complex to post the full code, so I tried to break down the problem into a simpler version - only to figure out that my basic example works flawlessly.

However, I am still stuck trying to run my application and would appreciate any input on the following - very helpful - error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffdd921f38 in main_arena () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

This occurs, when I try to call `getType()` along these lines:

```
std::map<long, QVAbstractElement *> mElements;

<...>//skipping some stuff

LineElement * insert_el = new LineElement();
mElements[0] = insert_el;

<...>//skipping a lot more stuff

AbstractElement * el = mElements.at(0);

if (!el)
{
    printf("ERROR");
    return (1);
}

int t = el->getType();
```

In this case, I know that the pointer `el` is valid, but the actual object is a `LineElement`, which was derived from `AbstractElement` and `getType()` is a `virtual` function only implemented in the base class (`AbstractElement`). When debugging with gdb I get the following pointer address:

```
(gdb) x el
0x11cf600:  0xdd921f48
(gdb) p el
$1 = (class AbstractElement *) 0x11cf600
```

Now, when trying to call that function (`getType`) from gdb, I get the following and :

```
(gdb) x el->getType()
warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `AbstractElement' value
warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `AbstractElement' value
```

Essentially, I think that even though my pointer check works and the address is still the same compared to time of creating this object, I can not call any of this object's functions.

**FIRST QUESTION**: Could this have anything to do with calling from different threads - I am using Qt for my UI and not 100% sure if Qt might be creating it's own threads?

**SECOND QUESTION**: Does this might actually just mean the problem could be anywhere in my code and this is just a messed up function table as the result?

Comment: You don't get the concept of a "minimal working example" - you have to continuously remove code and check for bug. When the bug dissapears, undo the last change and you've got your minimal working example. And you'll probably find out what's causing the segfault. What you've posted so far is not really helpful. For example, from what you say, I doubt that you "know" that `el` is valid pointer. You only know that it's not NULL, but I'll bet it's pointing at some garbage, which is causing the segfault. You're overwriting something you shouldn't ovewrite. I'd recomend trying valgrind.

Comment: Thanks - I checked the address of this pointer on creation and it's the same - that's why I believe it should be fine, but of course you are right and something else could overwrite it.

Comment: You probably have a buffer overrun or a similar memory error. Try `valgrind`.

Comment: You probably have a buffer overrun or a similar memory error. Try `valgrind`.

Comment: `el` has probably been destructed by that time, which is why its vtable pointer is no longer valid.

Comment: thanks for your replies - I will give valgrind a try to see what actually happens

Comment: I just stumbled across this post again and my original "answer" has been removed since. **The reason was indeed a bug in my code (as people expected) that deleted the element in question**.